# Bind function only works on last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am creating an application to store my homeworks, whenever I touch the li of the homework, the information of this homework yould be displayed from a sqlite database. My problem is that when I add each li from javascript, I bind a function so that each time I touch the item it will return its uid. But whenever I add a new hw, the other ones wont return their uid.

Some of my code:

```
function newFormSuccess(tx, results){
    var lista = $("#lHw");
    var obj = $(
        '<li><a id="' + results.id + '" href="#detalle" data-uid=' + results.id +
        ' class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse">' +
        '<h2>' + results.title + '</h2>' +
        '<p>' + results.desc + '</p><p>' + results.date + '</p>' +
        '<p class="ui-li-aside">Type</p></a>' +
        '</li>'
    );
    obj.find('#' + results.id).bind('click', function (e) {
        $.id = $(this).data('uid');
    });
    lista.append(obj).listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.changePage("#home");
}
```

Any suggestions? Why is this happening?

Comment: Before posting an answer for you, I want to encourage you to look into jQuery's [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Delegate. See the docs, quick syntax change and you'll be running.

Comment: Thank you!! I managed to solve it, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by changing the bind to .on, and using it ona a device ready function, I think this is what the Delegate comments where all about.

```
$("#lHw").on("click", "li a", function(e){
        $.id= $(this).data('uid');
    });
```